# Selenium Webdriver - Relative path not working in a popup dialog box

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, relative-path

Webdriver cannot find the element in a popup dialog box when I use a relative path for it. but, if I use the Absolute path it will identify the element. how can I solve this problem? 
I'm using selenium java.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(btnUpdateProductGroup));
btnUpdateProductGroup.click();
```

`html/body/div[7]/div[3]/a` - this xpath is working

`//a[@class='button'][Text()='Update']` - is not working (xpath is correct as evaluated using Firepath)

[image]

Comment: Can you add your html code?

Comment: how are you so sure xpath is correct? have you tried to detect that using firefox or chrome add-ons?

Comment: @Chathura, How many matching node you are seeing if evaluate same in firepath ?

Comment: @Tukes,  I found only one matching node

Comment: Share the URL please if it is public. Thanks

Comment: it's not a public URL. but Thanks for your help

Comment: how about this `//a[@class='button'][contains(text(),'Update')]` or `//span[@class=pie16 pie16-update']/../a`